# Broken theme after WordPress update

Tags: wordpress

I just updated to WordPress 4.8.3 to find that my custom parent theme is broken. It's been a while since I've worked on it, so I'm not completely fresh on everything, but the error in WordPress is as follows:

`Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a index.php template file. Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet.`

I don't need the `Template` header because this isn't a child theme and my theme folder *does* have an `index.php` template in `~/www/website/wp-content/themes/theme/`. Has anyone else encountered this? Googling just points to the solution being the missing `Template` header in `style.css`. Thanks in advance.

My `style.css` only contains the following headers:

```
/*
Theme Name: Portfolio
Theme URI: http://www.website.com
Author: Author Name
Author URI: http://www.website.com
Description: Custom theme converted from Bootstrap template
Version: 1.1
*/
```

Comment: well maybe check which theme is activated right now. All themes require style.css headers that include theme name, etc. Also try rolling back your wp-admin and wp-includes folder to your prev version may give you some insight.

Comment: @TurtleTread WordPress defaulted to the 2016 theme because mine isn't usable anymore. On the themes page, it says `The following themes are installed but incomplete.` along with the error I mentioned.

Comment: Did you put the theme header info into your style.css? and make sure Template line is not present for that theme because it looks like WP sees it as a child theme.

Comment: @TurtleTread No, as I mentioned, I didn't put the template header in my CSS as it's not a child theme. I've updated my post with the headers I have at the moment.

Comment: hmm empty your theme's index.php to just <?php and try activate the theme again? see what error do you get. You are not caching logged in pages right. any caching plugin active?

Comment: @TurtleTread Same error if `index.php` is empty. I also tried purging all caches with W3 Total Cache.

Answer (score 1):

In case this happens to anyone else, the solution was moving my `style.css` into the theme's root directory. Previously, it was in a `css` folder, which worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up! I was having such a hard time finding an answer to this. I also couldn't find anywhere that said style.css was required to be at the root.